# Novel with galaxy divided up among Earth nations, enemy aliens controlled by parasites, and teleporting hero

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

In the early 1980s I skimmed a book in the high school library (possibly in the B-section, because I used to think it was a Biggle or Brunner).  It had the following elements (I hope these are all from the same book):

- The first or second chapter talks about how once interstellar travel was discovered, humans decided to "project" Earth's national boundaries indefinitely into space, so the US would control everything above it (presumably at some particular time), China  the planets "above" it, etc.
- Humans encountered an apparently evil alien species that would eat humans if they were captured.  Eventually, the hero learns that the aliens are controlled by an internal parasite (perhaps because someone on his ship eats an alien in some sort of twisted revenge).
- While alone on a ship, the hero discovers he can teleport from one place to another on the ship - but because he's alone, he initially is concerned that he's been blacking out, and just walking from place to place, and only imagining that he's teleporting.

Comment: I guess they forgot that the Earth rotates.

Comment: I think they picked one particular day and time to set their boundaries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A possible match is Charles Runyon's *[I, Weapon](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/4213149-i-weapon)*.

Earth divides the universe into quadrants. The parasites happened after an Arabic colony, if I remember correctly, ate an infested animal. The aliens are worm-like parasites, although humanity thinks their enemies are a set of three-legged aliens, which are routinely infested by these worms. The main hero is the grandchild, or great-grandchild, of a lengthy eugenics program involving far-flung evolved forms of humanity. He can teleport, and has immense psychic abilities that border on reality control.

First paragraph of [the book](https://archive.org/details/iweapon00runy):

> Human history since the sidereal year one of space, the year 1970 of the Gregorian calendar, the year 1390 of the Muslim calendar, saw the outpouring of the human race into the surrounding spiral arm of the galaxy. Planets hung like ripe fruit free for the picking, and the Directing Council, set up to judge conflicting boundary claims, made the genocidal wars over colonies no longer valid. In a flash of anthropocentric benevolence the D.C. telemapped the entire visible universe and reserved for each race and political group a conical section of Creation extending into infinity, with each point anchored upon the planet earth.

Second page:

> The Vim regarded erect bipedal humanoids as domestic animals, to be ridden, worked, and eaten. Humans looked upon all scaly, tailed marsupials as creatures to be avoided, eaten, or stomped underfoot. Irony coupled with destiny to arrange that the Sa'al spaceship should land in the only valley then inhabited by the Vim crop tenders. The Arabs were an elite paramilitary group, composed of officers, soldiers, and their wives and concubines. For such men, to encounter resistance is to draw one's dagger — and there was no doubt that the Vim were hostile from the moment the Arabs began setting up their defense perimeter. The Vim saw their crops being trampled and ground to pulp by the vehicles of the colonists; they attacked with bare hands and macelike tails — and were burned. Those who ran were hunted down and eaten, since the Arabs were starved for meat after a three-year diet of ship concentrates.

Comment: Thank you - this cover https://www.amazon.com/I-weapon-Charles-W-Runyon/dp/0385064918 looks familiar, and this review https://schlock-value.com/2014/05/11/i-weapon/ mentions that the aliens are called "Vim" which sounds really familiar.  It's amazing that a high school library in rural Pennsylvania would have a book with the amount of sex that the review describes.  I don't know if I'll  ever look for a copy of this book, but I think you've id'ed it.

Comment: @Andrew: Heh, I checked it out of a small town library in Ashland, KY as a child.

Comment: Hmm.  Small town librarians apparently realize that parents won't read the books and that kids can keep a secret, I guess.